# Deleting the table row in tableview is not working in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

i am very new to objective c .I am trying to delete the table row from uitableview. whenever i trying to delete the first row of the tableview i am getting the following exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'" i don't what is the mistake i done.

can anyone please suggest me what is the mistake i done?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                     alertControllerWithTitle:@"alert"
                                     message:@"Are you want to delete the selected date."
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction* canclebutton = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"CANCEL"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                        //Handle your yes please button action here

                                    }];
        UIAlertAction* continuebutton = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"CONTINUE"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                       NSString *userid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                                           stringForKey:@"UserId"];
                                       NSString *encodeddistrictvalue = [selecteddistrictvalue stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
                                       NSString *encodedPanchaytvalue = [selectedpanchayatvalue stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
                                       NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my web service url"];NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
                                       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

                                       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                                                          queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                  NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
                                        {
                                            if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
                                            {
                                                NSDictionary *dictionaryvalue = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                                options:0
                                                                                                                  error:NULL];
                                                NSString *code = [[dictionaryvalue objectForKey:@"code"] stringValue];
                                                NSLog(@"the response string value is %@",code);
                                                if ([code intValue]==1) {

                                                    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
                                                    NSLog(@"the second button to naviagte %@",selectedIndexPath);
                                                    [assessmentnumber removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                                                    [tableView reloadData];

                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    NSLog(@"alredy deleted");
                                                    [assessmentnumber removeAllObjects];
                                                    [_tableview reloadData];
                                                }
                                            }


                                        } ];



}];
        [alert addAction:canclebutton];
        [alert addAction:continuebutton];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        alert.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you again calculating indexpath using        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];        Indexpath is already given in argument of this delegate method       "commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath"

Comment: For just checking the index path is selected correctly or not.i didn't use anywhere that selectedindexpath

Comment: your following delegate method should be like :                                             -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return [assessmentnumber count];
}

Comment: yes sir my delegate method is same as u said.